# How to insert reactive input values from a shiny app into a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, r, shiny, rmysql, r-dbi

I created an online experiment with the **shiny** package for R. Let's say I have 3 **reactive values** called ***"toss", "decision"***  and "***rating"***.

Additionally, I launched a **MySQL** database on Amazon web service RDS. The version is **MySQL 5.6.22**. 

I successfully managed to to send non-reactive values- like the timestamp- to MySQL database. So I assume the problem is where to locate the code talking to MySQL within the Server.R code. For non-reactive values it works perfectly when the code is outside (before) the reactive server-function. But with reactive values I suppose it should be somewhere within. 

I tried this code:

```
Server.R  
   library(shiny)
   library(RMySQL)
   library(DBI)
    con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname="db", username="myname", password="mypassword", host="myhost.com", port=xxxx)
   function(input, output, session){
       sql <- reactive({
                paste("insert into scenario1 (toss, dec, rat, timestamp) 
                     values (",input$toss,",",input$decision,",",input$rating,"now())")
       })
       result<-reactive({dbSendQuery(con, sql())})
   }
```

This way, I do not get an error message. So maybe the error is within the `insert into`-code. 
Additionally, I'm not sure whether the packages that I used are ideal for this purpose. I tried out a lot of things. Whenever I add a reactive value by leaving it out of the SQL-quote it stops working. I'm starting to think that RMySQL is missing that feature. There is nothing about `insert into` in the manual.

Is anyone able to detect the mistake I made?

Comment: When do you want that sql run? I think you'll need to wrap your dbSendQuery in an `isolate()`.

Comment: @cory Thanks for your suggestion. Would I simply add `isolate(sql())` to my code? By doing this it still doesn't work. So I assume it is not that simple. 
I want that sql to run at the end of the shiny session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I could make the query run with this code:

```
writingMarks <- function(input){ 
    con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname="db", username="myname", password="mypassword", 
           host="myhost.com", port=xxxx)   
    result <- sprintf<-("insert into scenario1 (toss, dec, timestamp) values (%s,%s,%s)",
                input$toss, input$decision, "now()")
    dbSendQuery(con, result)
}
```

I could not make the `paste` query run. With `sprintf` there is less confusion with the commas.

And, yes I indeed had to add an `isolate()`. I inserted it into an `observe()`. So it looks like this:

```
observe({
    if (input$condition==1){
      isolate({
        writingMarks(input)
      })
    }
    return()
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in:

```
paste("insert into scenario1 (toss, dec, rat, timestamp)
values (",input$toss,",",input$decision,",",input$rating,"now())")
```

The issue is: No , before now():

```
paste("insert into scenario1 (toss, dec, rat, timestamp)
values (",input$toss,",",input$decision,",",input$rating,",now())")
```

That should make the query run. Look into prepared statements, that will prevent this kind of (very common everybody makes them) concatenation mistakes.